# Interacting with background view controllers when popover is shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, popover

I am presenting a popover on screen but I need to interact with a button present on the background view.

It is a "Done" button that needs to dismiss background view controller. 
How can I do this?

Basically, Is there any way to interact with the presenting view controller while the popover is still being presented on it?

Comment: how are you presenting your popover? Code please

Comment: I am using a library FTPopover to show a custom popover at a particular point.

Comment: show us some code and library link. I suspect the popover is for the complete view which is  disabling for you to touch the view behind. Just create a simple popover with animation with a small frame and you can interact with the view behind it.

Comment: either you place that done button on your popover view or just finish interaction with the popover first.

Comment: Yes, The popover is for the complete view. The library I'm using is https://github.com/liufengting/FTPopOverMenu

Comment: was able to fix this by reducing the frame size. thanks!

Comment: @user2604897: If you are using inbuilt iOS popover present functionality then there is no way to interact with background controllers. What you can do is create your custom view, show/animate as like popover that way all background views are accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not have an answer until you specify the FTPopover Library as you mentioned.  Plus, as long as your popover view doesn't cover your "DONE" button, you still can press it as I reckon.

Answer (score 0):

I randomly stumbled upon this old question, and wanted to suggest the "passthroughViews" property:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipopoverpresentationcontroller/1622312-passthroughviews

This will let you interact with those views without the popover being dismissed.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, inside your dismissPopover method :

```
[self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: have you read the ques above before suggesting code here directly ?

Answer (score -1):

You can check the concept of delegate. Using this you can call method of background view controller from popover. Let me know if you want any further help.